# Strange behavior in rspec when raising exception

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to figure out why the following spec won't pass when the expect and actual results look the same

```
1) Moodle::Client raises moodle error if token is invalid
     Failure/Error: expect {
       expected Moodle::MoodleError with {"exception"=>"moodle_exception", "errorcode"=>"invalidtoken", "message"=>"Invalid token - token not found"}, got #<Moodle::MoodleError: {"exception"=>"moodle_exception", "errorcode"=>"invalidtoken", "message"=>"Invalid token - token not found"}> with backtrace:
         # ./lib/moodle/client.rb:27:in `resolve_request'
         # ./lib/moodle/client.rb:11:in `method_missing'
         # ./spec/moodle/client_spec.rb:48:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Moodle>'
         # ./spec/moodle/client_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Moodle>'
         # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr/util/variable_args_block_caller.rb:9:in `call'
         # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr/util/variable_args_block_caller.rb:9:in `call_block'
         # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr.rb:182:in `use_cassette'
         # ./spec/moodle/client_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Moodle>'
     # ./spec/moodle/client_spec.rb:47:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Moodle>'
     # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr/util/variable_args_block_caller.rb:9:in `call'
     # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr/util/variable_args_block_caller.rb:9:in `call_block'
     # /Users/ryanme/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@phoenix/gems/vcr-2.9.3/lib/vcr.rb:182:in `use_cassette'
     # ./spec/moodle/client_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Moodle>'
```

The code is still work in progress:

```
require 'typhoeus'

module Moodle
  class Client
    attr_reader :web_service_name, :filter_params

    def method_missing message, *args, &block
      if supports_web_service? message
        @web_service_name = message
        @filter_params = args.first
        resolve_request
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def supports_web_service? name
      true # change to look at configuration for web services
    end

    def resolve_request
      response = request.run

      json_body = JSON.parse(response.body)

      if json_body['exception']
        raise MoodleError, json_body
      else
        json_body
      end
    end

    def request
      Typhoeus::Request.new(Moodle.configuration.api_url,
                            method: :post,
                            params: request_params,
                            headers: { 'Accept' => "json" })
    end

    def request_params
      filter_params.merge!({ moodlewsrestformat: Moodle.configuration.format,
                             wsfunction: web_service_name,
                             wstoken: Moodle.configuration.token })
    end
  end
end
```

The spec spec is below:

```
it 'raises moodle error if token is invalid' do
      Moodle.configure do|c|
        c.host = 'http://dev.vle.getsmarter.co.za'
        c.token = 'invalidtoken'
      end

      expected_response = {"exception"=>"moodle_exception","errorcode"=>"invalidtoken","message"=>"Invalid token - token not found"}
      VCR.use_cassette("valid_service_with_invalid_token") do
        expect {
          Moodle::Client.new.core_user_get_users(params)
        }.to raise_error(Moodle::MoodleError, expected_response)
      end
    end
```

My question is why is it breaking? Does it have something to do with the backtrace? Also any ideas on how to fix it would be great.

Comment: Does this work without using VCR, i.e. hitting the real service?

Comment: No. The problem is not the exception. It seems to be something with the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`raise_error`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) doesn't take a hash but an error message (either string or regexp).

This would work:

```
expect {
  Moodle::Client.new.core_user_get_users(params)
}.to raise_error(Moodle::MoodleError, 'Invalid token - token not found')
```

You can set additional expectations by [passing a block](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher#set-expectations-on-error-object-passed-to-block), e.g.:

```
expect {
  Moodle::Client.new.core_user_get_users(params)
}.to raise_error(Moodle::MoodleError, 'Invalid token - token not found') { |error|
  expect(error.errorcode).to eq('invalidtoken')
}
```

Comment: Would the error_code be a custom field on the `MoodleError` ?

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes yes, it's just an attribute